# how to tell clang-format not put ';' to new line?

Tags: clang-format

My **C** code like this:

```c
while(true);

for(int i=100;i--;);
```

if i use clang-format, it will be replace like this:

```c
while(true)
;

for(int i=100;i--;)
;
```

I just try this, but it do not work:
*AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Always
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: AllIfsAndElse*

I don't want the ';' on newline, how to do it?

Comment: Use `while(true) {}`. This is better readable, a reader sees the intentional empty loop body and doesn't suspect a typo.

Comment: I know `while(true){}` but `while(true);` will type easy and faster.